# Unreal Engine compilation error every time I open my project

Tags: compiler-errors, unreal-blueprint

I recently started using Unreal Engine, and I am encountering an compilation error every time I open my project.

I am new to Unreal and only started using it last week. I mostly use the blueprints for programming but I also had to use some C++ to create some utilities nodes.

My problem is that the utilities nodes I created in C++ shows a compilation error every time I open the project, requiring me to go to each one and refresh it.

[image]

This is how I defined the node in C++:

```cpp
// header file
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Kismet/BlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "BoxUtils.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class MYDEMOPROJECT_API UBoxUtils : public UBlueprintFunctionLibrary
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    static bool areBoxesIntersecting(const FBox boxA, const FBox boxB);
    
};

// code file
#include "BoxUtils.h"

bool UBoxUtils::areBoxesIntersecting(const FBox boxA, const FBox boxB)
{
    return boxA.Intersect(boxB);
}
```

Can someone please explain how can I resolve this problem? It is very annoying to refresh those nodes one-by-one every time I open my project.